# What is my word?

Tags: word

I have a word. In the middle of my word are the letters 'ergro'. There are three letters at the start and the end of my word. The three letters at the start of my word are the same as the three letters at the end.

What is my word?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think its

> **Und**ergro**und**.

So far this is the only *English* word I could find that worked with this.

Comment: Overground..............................                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Wombling free?

Answer (score 29):

Litscape claims there is another:

> **sup**ergro**ups**

It appears to be a music thing.

Comment: This works, but the letters are not in the same order.

Comment: @Kslkgh: Well, technically, you only said the letters were the same, you didn't state they had to be in the same order.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yeah, sorry.

Comment: I actually liked it more *because* the letters weren't in the same order.

Comment: @EngineerToast I'm not sure why. I'd give the edge to the word that has it in the same order since the question is asking for the first three to be the same as the last three. 'Und' is "more same" with 'und' than 'sup' is to 'ups'. Either way I would say that both answers are correct, but I don't see why your answer should have more votes... Reputation bias? I know you probably don't have anything to do with that, just struck me as odd..

Comment: @Warlord099 I think "underground" should have more votes because it was first by several hours but not just because its letters are in the same order. I think that makes it a more interesting word but not a better fit to the puzzle.

Comment: @EngineerToast Lol, well I agree with you there. And actually I wasn't trying to imply that 'underground' should have *more* votes. I was just trying to say that I didn't see a reason why it should have *less* votes like it did at the time of the comment  (and actually the time difference was included with my reasoning, just not explicitly stated because that wasn't the main point of my comment).

Answer (score 3):

Words of 11 letters with matching triplets start and end:

```
antioxidant
entitlement
microcosmic
redelivered
tessellates
underground <-- voila
```

And if the order of the triplet letters is malleable:

```
hypertrophy
stealthiest
researchers
restrainers
abracadabra
earthenware
encumbrance
sacroiliacs
sanitarians
shellfishes
inoculation
trendsetter
```

But annoyingly none that I can see which end in the opposite order to the start.

Of the above, we can see that some have 4 matching letters:

```
redelivered
abracadabra
sanitarians
```

And there is in fact a 9-letter which packs 2 4-letter repeats:

```
outshouts
```

The patterns for those who are `grep -P` ready:

```
^(...).{5}\1$       // 11 letters, common start and end triplet

^(....).+\1$        // 4-letter repeats

// unordered matching end triple
^(.)(.)(.).{5}(\1(\2\3|\3\2)|\2(\1\3|\3\1)|\3(\1\2|\2\1))$
```

Comment: Im guessing you wrote some script for this? If so could you provide it in your answer?

Comment: @Aʟᴀɢᴀʀᴏs: updated answer accordingly. No script per se, just patters to use with grep and a word list.